# If the IOTA Foundation runs out of money, who will continue the development?

Tags: iota-network

Is the IOTA ecosystem strong enough to continue developing IOTA?

Answer (score 3):

The IOTA Foundation says that they have enough funds to last several years but their money is in the form of IOTA tokens. If the price of these tokens goes down, the IOTA Foundation won't have enough money to continue the development.

The ecosystem around the IOTA project shows promise but it is not quite developed and it will probably does not have the required resources to continue the development.

To see how many months the IF has left check https://www.notion.so/cleaniota/15b406b0b914426ba48252d88e89804d?v=33fe4d2a3f554b5dbc746bc64cca32db

Answer (score 2):

Google "iota foundation funding" and it points you to their site https://www.iota.org/foundation/vision-and-mission :

"Funding

```
Holdings of IOTA tokens from community donations.

Research and development grants from public bodies.

Contributions from individuals or organisations.
```

"

Since they are a German non-profit, their financial should be public, but I don't have the time to search those for you.

Comment: There is nothing to search. Their financials are not public, as Dominik Schiener has acknowledged himself. The grants awarded (450,423 €) aren't enough to cover 2 weeks of operations at their current burn rate. https://ec.europa.eu/transparencyregister/public/consultation/displaylobbyist.do?id=500027331119-04

Answer (score 1):

The IF has received various grants by the EU and will also try to do so in the future. Example: https://blog.iota.org/in-the-last-couple-of-years-the-iota-foundation-started-to-proactively-participate-in-ae28ddb38639/

Comment: On 18 February 2021 I revealed that, by refusing to update their public financial information, the IF was failing to abide by the code of conduct of the EU Transparency Register and threatened to lodge a formal complaint. After three reminders and one day before the deadline I gave, the IOTA Foundation updated their information in the EU Transparency Register. The update revealed that the IOTA Foundation has been awarded, but not yet received, a meager 450,423 €, insufficient to cover two weeks of operations at their current burn rate.